# using variable as part of variable name of others in django

Tags: python, django

I am now trying to do this...

```
{% for item in item_list %}
    <p>{{ result_??? }}</p><br>
{% endfor %}
```

and I want to put `{{item}}` there.

E.g. the passed in item_list is

```
['A', 'B', 'C']
```

and I want to do something equivalent to below using the for-loop:

```
<p>{{ result_A }}</p><br>
<p>{{ result_B }}</p><br>
<p>{{ result_C }}</p><br>
```

where result_A, result_B, result_C is also passed in using the render function.

The problem is, how do I script the script? 
i.e. how do can I use a variable as a part of another variable?
(or is there a smarter way to do this?)

Comment: Can you exactly or by an example clarify what do you mean with *use variable as a part of another variable* ?

Comment: Are you passing all the variables in the context say item_A, item_B... etc? You should rather pass them in an array.

Comment: use jinja2! then {{ result[item] }} works!

Comment: Can you post the code from your controller?

Comment: so in the python code on the back, I have `context['item_list'] = ['A', 'B', 'C']` and `context['result_A'] = '1'`, `context['result_B'] = '2'`, `context['result_C'] = '3'`. Then I render the context and I want to do something in above post in html using django to print {{ result_A }} etc.

Answer (score 0):

it is unclear where those result_... variables are defines and how they are present in the template, maybe as @arocks said they are in the template context variable, in any case, these kind of manipulations are better done in django view rather than the template